# Solving differential equation with initial condition

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I've got:

$$y''=3y'$$ where $y(3) = 1$ and $y'(3) = 2$.

I tried saying:

$$y''-3y' = 0 \\ \Rightarrow r^2-3r = 0$$

so $r = 3$ or $0$. The solution is therefore given as:

$$y=Ae^{3t} + Be^0 = Ae^{3t} +B$$

According to my book, by auxiliary equations.

But I'm not sure if I'm doing this right? If so, how do I finish?

Comment: whoops. Let me edit

Comment: You forgot your variable. There should be an $x$ (or a $t$) in the exponent.

Answer (score 2):

The differential equation is $y^{\prime \prime} - 3y^{\prime} = 0$. You get the characteristic polynomial $\lambda(\lambda - 3) = 0$. So you get $y = Ae^{3t} + B$ as your general form equation.

You then solve:
$y(3) = 1 = Ae^{9} + B$

$y^{\prime}(3) = 2 = 3Ae^{9}$

Comment: What did you differentiate with respect to?

Comment: Your function is $y(t)$. So I took $\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Comment: $y(x) = Ae^{3t} + B$.

$y'(x) = 3Ae^{3t}$.

Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my way of solving it:Let $y^{'}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}=z$. Then,
$$\dfrac{dz}{dx}=3z\\
\implies z=Ce^{3x}\\
\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}=Ce^{3x}\\
\implies \int dy=C\int e^{3x}dx\\
\implies y=\dfrac{C}{3}e^{3x}+c$$
So,
$$A=\dfrac{C}{3},B=c$$
If $y'(3)=2$, then
$$Ce^{9}=2\\
\implies C=\dfrac{2}{e^9}$$
Thus,
$$y=\dfrac{2}{3e^9}e^{3x}+c$$
As $y(3)=1$,
$$1=\dfrac{2}{3e^9}e^{3}+c\\
\implies c=1-\dfrac{2}{3e^9}e^{3}$$
Thus,
$$\boxed{y=\dfrac{2}{3e^9}e^{3x}+1-\dfrac{2}{3e^9}e^{3}}\\
A=\dfrac{2}{3e^9},B=1-\dfrac{2}{3e^9}e^{3}$$

Comment: Don't you mean $$A = \frac{2}{3e^9}$$ ?

Comment: @Paze Yes, typo.